# StackOverflowError: null

Tags: java, null

Can someone please help me spot the error here? I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this main code. I'll give out the secondary one in order to supplement the details. The error I'm receiving is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError:
null
```

Main code:

```
public class Line
{
private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
private double Slope;

public Line(int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2)
{
    Line test = new Line(a1, b1, a2, b2);
}

public void setCoordinates(int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2)
{
   a1=x1;
   b1=y2;
   a2=x2;
   b2=y2;   
}

public void calculateSlope( )
{
    Slope = (x2-x1)/(y2-y1);
    Slope = (double)Slope;   
}

public void printSlope( )
{
    System.out.printf("The slope is %.2f" , Slope);
}
}
```

Secondary code:

```
public class LineRunner

{
 public static void main( String[] args )
  {

    Line test = new Line(1, 9, 10, 11);
    test.calculateSlope();
    test.printSlope();

    test= new Line (1, 7, 18, 3);
    test.calculateSlope();
    test.printSlope();

    test = new Line(6, 4, 2, 2);
    test.calculateSlope();
    test.printSlope();

    test = new Line(4, 4, 5, 3);
    test.calculateSlope();
    test.printSlope();

    test = new Line(1, 1, 2, 9);
    test.calculateSlope();
    test.printSlope();

  }
}
```

Comment: Please get rid of all that unnecessary and distracting white space in your posted code. One blank line is more than enough in any one place.

Comment: That isn't the error you're getting.  Java errors come with a wall of information.  Give us that wall, or at least the start of that wall.

Comment: Although the given answers are correct, I'd like to point out that your 'calculateSlope' method will do Integer division, and as such not result in a precise number, as you seem to want. Instead of assigning the slope variable twice, assigning it to "(x2-x1)/(double)(y2-y1)" should give you a more precise number.

Answer (score 1):

The `Line` constructor calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which causes `StackOverflowError`:

```
Line test = new Line(a1, b1, a2, b2);
```

You probably meant for it to call `setCoordinates()`:

```
setCoordinates(a1, b1, a2, b2);
```

Except that won't work, because it actually is:

```
public void setCoordinates(int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2)
{
    a1 = this.x1;
    b1 = this.y2;
    a2 = this.x2;
    b2 = this.y2;
}
```

You probably meant to assign the other way.

Comment: Thank you so much. Anyway, I'm just wondering is there an alternative to the keyword, "this"?

Comment: Alternative is not using it, like you did, and that leads to errors like you had. Always using `this` is a good idea, because it helps readers of your code (and yourself) to understand that you are referring to an instance field, and not a local variable/parameter.